# Is There A Way To Use Devexpress.Xamarin.Android.Charts From Xamarin.Forms PCL Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, devexpress

There's a chart library with Custom UI Controls from DevExpress that I'd like to use for reports but they only have two platform specific libraries for the library which are for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. Nothing for Xamarin.Forms. Is there anything I can do to be able to use both these libraries from the Xamarin.Forms project instead of having to write platform specific code for both projects, which totally defeats the purpose of Xamarin?

Comment: you would  typically use DependencyService to inject the platform specific behavior into your shared code.  Alternatively, you could  use a custom renderer, which might make more sense for a UI  control.

Comment: It needs custom renderer(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) or dependency(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to do it.

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress Native Charts support the Xamarin.Forms platform starting with v1.1 (see [Native UI Controls - Charts v1.1 CTP with Xamarin.Forms support](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/analytics/archive/2018/09/14/Native-UI-Controls-Charts-v1.1-CTP-with-Xamarin.Forms-support.aspx)).

So, if you have the latest version (v1.1.4), you will be able to integrate DevExpress Charts components into a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform solution.

Refer to the [Charts for Xamarin.Forms](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/400422/xamarin-forms/index) and [Xamarin.Forms API Reference](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.Charts) documentation articles for additional information.